# How to Check for Even numbers in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, if-statement

I have a problem with `if` and `if else`.
I wrote a snippet of code that asks for a person's personal signum and then takes the 9th element out.
But I simply can not find a way where by using `if-else` to check whether it is an even number or not, in order to determine if the person is a male or female.
This how my code looks so far:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace övning_14
    {
        class ålder
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string personNummer; 
                string indata;
                Console.Write("vad är ditt person signum ? "); // simply asks for the num
                indata = Console.ReadLine();
                personNummer = indata;
                kön = int.Parse(personNummer.Substring(9, 1));
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Use the remainder operator `%`, e.g. `isEven = i % 2 == 0`

Comment: yes i did but i only got vague answers, mostly just poped up formilas but not explaining their use

Comment: If you question is answered, please close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check the the kön variable.

```
public static bool IsEven(int value)
{
    return value % 2 == 0;
}
```

Now you can call

```
if (IsEven(kön) == true)
{
    // even number 
}
else
{
    // Not even
}
```

For a description of the % operator in C# you can check MSDN: [% Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try something along the lines of

```
if(kön % 2 == 0)
{
//Even number
}
```

Comment: While possibly correct, this answer doesn't explain anything and the question itself is questionable as he has clearly not even done a google search.

Comment: @Ashigore that doesnt make sense, if his question is wrong downvote the question. If somebody is using google to find a solution to a question like this there is a change of them hitting this question. Only seeing a downvoted answer might let them think it is wrong?

Comment: Yes you are right however, your answer is a bad answer to a bad question which in my opinion should not have been dignified with an answer.

Comment: f.y.i.well i did search on iformation on google but all i got was vague answers if you think my question was questionable the please deliberate on exactly how i could improved it?

Answer (score 0):

The Following code

```
  public string evenodd(int value)
    {
        if(value % 2 == 0)
        {
        return "Even";
        }
        else
        {
        return "Odd";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, this will also works

```
if((val / 2).ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).Contains("."))
{
    // odd
}
else
{
    // even
}
```